# Cloudformation does not support create vpc links in apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

In aws api gateway there is a section called API Link and I can manually set that.
[image]

The problem is I cannot find any section in cloudformation documentation on how I can create vpc link via cloud formation on api gateway.
Is it sth that cloudformation does not support or am I missing it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use swagger to define an API Gateway using VPC Link. This is a complete CloudFormation template you can deploy to test it out...

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Test backend access via API Gateway. This template provisions a Regional API Gateway proxing requests to a backend via VPC Link and Direct Connect to on-premises resources using private ip addresses.",
    "Parameters": {
        "VPCId": {
            "Description": "VPC Id for API Gateway VPC Link",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },
        "NLBSubnetList": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "Subnet Ids for provisioning load balancer supporting the VPC Link"
        },
        "BackendBaseEndpoint": {
            "Description": "The backend service base url including protocol. e.g.: https://<url>",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "https://mybackend.dev.mycompany.com"
        },
        "TargetIpAddresses": {
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description": "Comma separated list of NLB target ip addresses. Specify two entries.",
            "Default": "10.78.80.1, 10.79.80.1"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "API": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "Test Api",
                "Description": "Test Api using VPC_LINK and AWS_IAM authorisation",
                "Body": {
                    "swagger": "2.0",
                    "info": {
                        "title": "Test Api"
                    },
                    "schemes": [
                        "https"
                    ],
                    "paths": {
                        "/{proxy+}": {
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
                                "parameters": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "proxy",
                                        "in": "path",
                                        "required": true,
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "responses": {},
                                "security": [
                                    {
                                        "sigv4": []
                                    }
                                ],
                                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                    "responses": {
                                        "default": {
                                            "statusCode": "200"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "requestParameters": {
                                        "integration.request.path.proxy": "method.request.path.proxy"
                                    },
                                    "uri": {
                                        "Fn::Join": [
                                            "",
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "BackendBaseEndpoint"
                                                },
                                                "/{proxy}"
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
                                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                                    "connectionId": "${stageVariables.vpcLinkId}",
                                    "httpMethod": "GET",
                                    "type": "http_proxy"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "securityDefinitions": {
                        "sigv4": {
                            "type": "apiKey",
                            "name": "Authorization",
                            "in": "header",
                            "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "awsSigv4"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "EndpointConfiguration": {
                    "Types": [
                        "REGIONAL"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": "VPCLink"
        },
        "APIStage": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Properties": {
                "StageName": "dev",
                "Description": "dev Stage",
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "API"
                },
                "DeploymentId": {
                    "Ref": "APIDeployment"
                },
                "MethodSettings": [
                    {
                        "ResourcePath": "/*",
                        "HttpMethod": "GET",
                        "MetricsEnabled": "true",
                        "DataTraceEnabled": "true",
                        "LoggingLevel": "ERROR"
                    }
                ],
                "Variables": {
                    "vpcLinkId": {
                        "Ref": "VPCLink"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "APIDeployment": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
            "Properties": {
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "API"
                },
                "Description": "Test Deployment"
            }
        },
        "VPCLink": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::VpcLink",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "Vpc link to GIS platform",
                "Name": "VPCLink",
                "TargetArns": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "NLB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "NLBTargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "NLBTargetGroup",
                "Port": 443,
                "Protocol": "TCP",
                "TargetGroupAttributes": [
                    {
                        "Key": "deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds",
                        "Value": "20"
                    }
                ],
                "TargetType": "ip",
                "Targets": [
                    {
                        "Id": { "Fn::Select" : [ "0", {"Ref": "TargetIpAddresses"} ] },
                        "Port": 443,
                        "AvailabilityZone": "all"
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": { "Fn::Select" : [ "1", {"Ref": "TargetIpAddresses"} ] },
                        "Port": 443,
                        "AvailabilityZone": "all"
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPCId"
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Project",
                        "Value": "API and VPC Link Test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "NLB": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "Type": "network",
                "Scheme": "internal",
                "Subnets": {
                    "Ref": "NLBSubnetList"
                }
            }
        },
        "NLBListener": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties": {
                "DefaultActions": [
                    {
                        "Type": "forward",
                        "TargetGroupArn": {
                            "Ref": "NLBTargetGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "LoadBalancerArn": {
                    "Ref": "NLB"
                },
                "Port": "443",
                "Protocol": "TCP"
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "NetworkLoadBalancerArn": {
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "NLB"
            },
            "Description": "The network elastic load balancer Amazon resource name"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey when I run your code I get Encountered unsupported property ConnectionId. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, CloudFormation does not support API Gateway's VPC Links at this time.

You can create a [Lambda-backed custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to manage the VPC Link using CloudFormation.

Here is a Lambda function (using python3.6) for a CloudFormation custom resource I use to manage VPC links:

```
import copy
import json
import re
import time

import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests

SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
FAILED = "FAILED"
FAILED_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID = "FAILED_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID"


class AddOrUpdateTargetArnsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 'Target arns are not allowed to be changed/added.'
        super().__init__(self.message)


class FailedVpcLinkError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status_message):
        self.message = f'statusMessages: {status_message}'
        super().__init__(self.message)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        _lambda_handler(event, context)
    except Exception as e:
        send(
            event,
            context,
            response_status=FAILED,
            # Do not fail on delete to avoid rollback failure
            response_data=None,
            physical_resource_id=event.get('PhysicalResourceId', FAILED_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID),
            reason=e
        )
        # Must raise, otherwise the Lambda will be marked as successful, and the exception
        # will not be logged to CloudWatch logs.
        raise


def _lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: ")
    print(event)

    resource_type = event['ResourceType']
    if resource_type != "Custom::ApiGatewayVpcLink":
        raise ValueError(f'Unexpected resource_type: {resource_type}')

    request_type = event['RequestType']
    wait_for = event.get('WaitFor', None)
    resource_properties = event['ResourceProperties']
    physical_resource_id = event.get('PhysicalResourceId', None)

    apigateway = boto3.client('apigateway')

    if wait_for:
        handle_self_invocation(
            wait_for=wait_for,
            physical_resource_id=physical_resource_id,
            event=event,
            context=context,
        )
    else:
        if request_type == 'Create':
            kwargs = dict(
                name=resource_properties['Name'],
                targetArns=resource_properties['TargetArns'],
                description=resource_properties.get('Description', None)
            )
            response = apigateway.create_vpc_link(**kwargs)
            event_copy = copy.deepcopy(event)
            event_copy['WaitFor'] = 'CreateComplete'
            event_copy['PhysicalResourceId'] = response['id']

            print('Reinvoking function because VPC link creation is asynchronous')
            relaunch_lambda(event=event_copy, context=context)
            return

        elif request_type == 'Update':
            old_resource_properties = event['OldResourceProperties']

            current_target_arns = apigateway.get_vpc_link(
                vpcLinkId=physical_resource_id,
            )['targetArns']

            # must compare current_target_arns to resource_properties['TargetArns'], to protect against
            # UPDATE created by UPDATE_FAILED. In that particular case, current_target_arns will be the same as
            # resource_properties['TargetArns'] but different than old_resource_properties['TargetArns']
            if set(current_target_arns) != set(resource_properties['TargetArns']) and \
                    set(resource_properties['TargetArns']) != set(old_resource_properties['TargetArns']):
                raise AddOrUpdateTargetArnsError()

            patch_operations = []

            if resource_properties['Name'] != old_resource_properties['Name']:
                patch_operations.append(dict(
                    op='replace',
                    path='/name',
                    value=resource_properties['Name'],
                ))

            if 'Description' in resource_properties and 'Description' in old_resource_properties:
                if resource_properties['Description'] != old_resource_properties['Description']:
                    patch_operations.append(dict(
                        op='replace',
                        path='/description',
                        value=resource_properties['Description'],
                    ))
            elif 'Description' in resource_properties and 'Description' not in old_resource_properties:
                patch_operations.append(dict(
                    op='replace',
                    path='/description',
                    value=resource_properties['Description'],
                ))
            elif 'Description' not in resource_properties and 'Description' in old_resource_properties:
                patch_operations.append(dict(
                    op='replace',
                    path='/description',
                    value=None,
                ))

            apigateway.update_vpc_link(
                vpcLinkId=physical_resource_id,
                patchOperations=patch_operations,
            )

        elif request_type == 'Delete':
            delete = True

            if physical_resource_id == FAILED_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID:
                delete = False
                print('Custom resource was never properly created, skipping deletion.')

            stack_name = re.match("arn:aws:cloudformation:.+:stack/(?P<stack_name>.+)/.+", event['StackId']).group('stack_name')
            if stack_name in physical_resource_id:
                delete = False
                print(f'Skipping deletion, because VPC link was not created properly. Heuristic: stack name ({stack_name}) found in physical resource ID ({physical_resource_id})')

            logical_resource_id = event['LogicalResourceId']
            if logical_resource_id in physical_resource_id:
                delete = False
                print(f'Skipping deletion, because VPC link was not created properly. Heuristic: logical resource ID ({logical_resource_id}) found in physical resource ID ({physical_resource_id})')

            if delete:
                apigateway.delete_vpc_link(
                    vpcLinkId=physical_resource_id
                )
                event_copy = copy.deepcopy(event)
                event_copy['WaitFor'] = 'DeleteComplete'
                print('Reinvoking function because VPC link deletion is asynchronous')
                relaunch_lambda(event=event_copy, context=context)
                return

        else:
            print(f'Request type is {request_type}, doing nothing.')

        send(
            event,
            context,
            response_status=SUCCESS,
            response_data=None,
            physical_resource_id=physical_resource_id,
        )


def handle_self_invocation(wait_for, physical_resource_id, event, context):
    apigateway = boto3.client('apigateway')
    if wait_for == 'CreateComplete':
        print('Waiting for creation of VPC link: {vpc_link_id}'.format(vpc_link_id=physical_resource_id))
        response = apigateway.get_vpc_link(
            vpcLinkId=physical_resource_id,
        )
        status = response['status']
        print('Status of VPC link {vpc_link_id} is {status}'.format(vpc_link_id=physical_resource_id, status=status))

        if status == 'AVAILABLE':
            send(
                event,
                context,
                response_status=SUCCESS,
                response_data=None,
                physical_resource_id=physical_resource_id,
            )
        elif status == 'FAILED':
            raise FailedVpcLinkError(status_message=response['statusMessage'])
        elif status == 'PENDING':
            # Sleeping here to avoid polluting CloudWatch Logs by reinvoking the Lambda too quickly
            time.sleep(30)
            relaunch_lambda(event, context)
        else:
            print('Unexpected status, doing nothing')

    elif wait_for == 'DeleteComplete':
        print('Waiting for deletion of VPC link: {vpc_link_id}'.format(vpc_link_id=physical_resource_id))
        try:
            response = apigateway.get_vpc_link(
                vpcLinkId=physical_resource_id,
            )
        except apigateway.exceptions.NotFoundException:
            print('VPC link {vpc_link_id} deleted successfully'.format(vpc_link_id=physical_resource_id))
            send(
                event,
                context,
                response_status=SUCCESS,
                response_data=None,
                physical_resource_id=physical_resource_id,
            )
        else:
            status = response['status']
            assert status == 'DELETING', f'status is {status}'
            # Sleeping here to avoid polluting CloudWatch Logs by reinvoking the Lambda too quickly
            time.sleep(10)
            relaunch_lambda(event, context)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Unexpected WaitFor: {wait_for}')


def relaunch_lambda(event, context):
    boto3.client("lambda").invoke(
        FunctionName=context.function_name,
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(event),
    )


def send(event, context, response_status, response_data, physical_resource_id, reason=None):
    response_url = event['ResponseURL']

    response_body = {
        'Status': response_status,
        'Reason': str(reason) if reason else 'See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: ' + context.log_stream_name,
        'PhysicalResourceId': physical_resource_id,
        'StackId': event['StackId'],
        'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
        'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId'],
        'Data': response_data,
    }

    json_response_body = json.dumps(response_body)

    headers = {
        'content-type': '',
        'content-length': str(len(json_response_body))
    }

    try:
        requests.put(
            response_url,
            data=json_response_body,
            headers=headers
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("send(..) failed executing requests.put(..): " + str(e))
```

Comment: I came across this because I am trying to model an API gateway in CloudFormaiton. I see AWS have added the VPC link type (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-vpclink.html) but seemingly no way of using it. Currently there is no way to specify the connection id or connection type property  Does your code allow the use of a VPC link created in cloudformation to be used in the method integration? Can you show provide an example of how you use the custom resource please?

Comment: I have had a better look at the code here and it seems that it just creates the VPC link which you can now do using the new cfn type. Do you have similar code for updating the method integration to use the newly created VPC link ? It's very frustrating the AWS have created the VPC link type but not a way to use it!

Comment: I've just posted an answer with complete CloudFormation template using Swagger 2.0 below. Check it out...

Comment: It's 2022 already, still no?