# Not able to map VPC_LINK with Method Integration on Api Gateway using cloud formation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am using Cloudformation to configure API Gateway Method to use VPC Link.

Its not working.

Sample code is as below:

```
    ProxyResourceANY: 
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
        ResourceId: !Ref RestApiResource
        HttpMethod: ANY      
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        Integration:
            Type: HTTP_PROXY
            IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
            #ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
            #ConnectionId: !Ref VpcLink
            Uri: !Sub http://${LoadBalancerUrl}:8098
```

CloudFormation error:

```
Encountered unsupported property ConnectionId
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. CloudFormation errors with "Encountered unsupported property ConnectionId", and CF docs do not contain these properties https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html while other docs do https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/

Comment: i'm running into the same problem :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudformation does not support create vpc links in apigateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889735/cloudformation-does-not-support-create-vpc-links-in-apigateway)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use !Ref there but you have 2 solution for this :

Simply use !Sub instead of !Ref like this :

```
#ConnectionId: !Sub ${VpcLink}
```

Or more complex you can use stage variable :

Use a stage variable `"${stageVariables.variable}"` in your method instead of the reference to your VpcLink

```
ProxyResourceANY: 
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    ResourceId: !Ref RestApiResource
    HttpMethod: ANY      
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    Integration:
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
        ConnectionId: '${stageVariables.vpcLink}'
        Uri: !Sub http://${LoadBalancerUrl}:8098
```

And then set your stage variable referencing your VpcLink when you create your stage :

```
Stage:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
Properties: 
  StageName: 'Stage'
  Variables: 
    VpcLink: !Ref VpcLink
```

Comment: Just remember to use the same capitalized variables, instead `VpcLink: !Ref VpcLink` use `vpcLink: !Ref VpcLink` in order to match the line: `ConnectionId: '${stageVariables.vpcLink}'` otherwise you will get a 500 Internal Error message from the API